# copy range from one table to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

Latest code below....
Couple of issues -

1. paste copies data to Col3 on the destination sheet not col 1
2. I think may need to sort the source data by column a before selecting the data - I got an error saying could not run the command over multilple selections (unless there is another way to cup and paste it)
   3 after the update has been done could do with resize of the destination table to include all the new rows added as part of the table...

I have spent time looking into solving all these myself so I don't want you to think I am not trying :-)

Appreciate all the help being given!

```
   
    Dim MFST_LastRow As Long
    
    ' Get work sheet
    Set wsf = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
    Set wst = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    
    ' Get table
    Set tblMSFT = wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    Set tblMAV = wsf.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    
    'Sort Table
    

    
    End With
    
    
    ' Filter table
    tblMAV.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
    
    ' Copy filtered table
    tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Set visRange = tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set visRange = Application.Intersect(visRange, wsf.Columns("B:R"))
    
    visRange.Copy
    ' Get the last data row #
    With tblMAV.Range
        MFST_LastRow = wst.Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
        MsgBox (MFST_LastRow)
    End With
    
    ' Paste as values
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MsgBox ("B4 PASTE")
     wst.Cells(MFST_LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
  
        'tblMAV.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    MsgBox "New Records Added", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
       
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'========================================
```

Comment: am i missing something here...i can the question has been edited by other members but I am not seeing any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy a Specified Number of Columns From One Table to Another

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateMasterSupplier()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Update Master Supplier"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 2 ' 15 in your case according to comments
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = MapAndValidation
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    
    Dim srg As Range:
    
    With slo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
        With .DataBodyRange.Columns(FIRST_COLUMN).Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set srg = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching data found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = MasterSupplierFile
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    
    Dim drrg As Range:
    
    With dlo
        If .ListRows.Count = 0 Then
            Set drrg = .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT)
        Else
            With .Range
                Set drrg = .Resize(1, COLUMNS_COUNT).Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim sarg As Range, sarCount As Long
    
    For Each sarg In srg.Areas
        sarCount = sarg.Rows.Count
        drrg.Resize(sarCount).Value = sarg.Value
        Set drrg = drrg.Offset(sarCount)
    Next sarg
    
    MsgBox "Update complete.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: this never created any records in the destination  sheet... is it processing 1 record at a tome or copying a block of data?  The previous code was copying the data in one go it just wasn't copying the columns as I needed them to be copied ... if this is processing one record at a time then there is an Update record type I have in A1 which would need to perform an update rather than an add.... does that make sense

Comment: the source file could have 1000's of records which is why I thought the block copy would be better - I was then going to do a do loop to perform the check on Updates - and then updates the couple of columns I needed to change... am pretty new to this so not sure what the most effecient way to process will be

Comment: `PasteSpecial` messes with the selection so I'm avoiding it whenever possible. This code loops through the areas of the filtered range i.e. writes each 'block' of adjacent rows to the destination table by assignment, the fastest way to copy values of a range. I don't know what *"an Update record type"* is, sorry. BTW, you only have to change `COLUMNS_COUNT` to 15 and it should work as intended (described). Maybe take another look at the screenshot and try to figure out what is different (and let me know).

Comment: i have updated the text in the original post and added 2 images to explain what I am trying to achieve..

Comment: Brilliant just changed the First and last col values and bingo!!

Comment: would it be best to process all the NEW record Types and then Copy the Code and repeat for the UPDATES?

Comment: Thanks again for all your help last night... did the additional text and screenshots make sense?  Will it be better to copy the SUB you provided and adapt to perfrom the updates separatley? There is a unique Supplier ket that can be used for an xlookup..

Comment: I have been looking at the code trying understand how i may be able to copy it and create the update function but i am struggling to get it...would you be able to help me with the update function?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `Option Explicit` to prevent misspelling variable names. (eg. tblMSFT vs tblMFST)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateMasterSupplier()
    Dim wsf As Worksheet
    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Dim tblMSFT As ListObject
    Dim tblMAV As ListObject
    Dim MFST_LastRow As Long
    ' Get work sheet
    Set wsf = Sheets("MAPANDVALIDATION")
    Set wst = Sheets("MASTERSUPPLIERFILE")
    ' Get table
    Set tblMSFT = wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    Set tblMAV = wsf.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    ' Filter table
    tblMAV.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
    ' Copy filtered table
    tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    ' Get the last data row #
    With tblMAV.Range
        MFST_LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    End With
    ' Paste as values
    wst.Cells(MFST_LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    MsgBox ("Update Complete")
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Option Explicit statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

Update

> Question:the source table is in the TASK - MAP and Validation sheet and is MAV_Table - there is data in A to AN but I only want to copy B to P to MSF_Table A to O

```
    ' Copy filtered table
    Dim visRange As Range
    Set visRange = tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set visRange = Application.Intersect(visRange, wsf.Columns("B:O"))
    visRange.Copy
```

Comment: Thanks - the annotation is very helpful too....I tried this and got an error Subscript out of range on first set.wsf - I though it was as it was all caps - so changed to as it is defined in the  VBA project but is still get it?

Comment: The sheets' name is copied from OP. Please make sure it s exactly same as your file.

Comment: It looks same  - I just added a picture  - BTW really appreciate your help! I just cut and pasted it from NAME and still errors

Comment: think i figured it out - I had set those values previously in another try - I changed to the Sheer name TASK - Map And Validation and seems fins now

Comment: now the tblMAV.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New" statement is erroring Object out of range?

Comment: odd - I commented out what I pasted from hers and retyped it and the errors have now cleared?

Comment: Working now... apart from when I do the copy i need to select columns B:O...

Comment: No sure what does it mean? Please update your post with the detail. What's the range of `tblMSFT`?

Comment: Once i have filtered the data in the sheet TASK - Map and Validation I only want to copy the data in columns B:O into the MASTER - Supplier File starting in column A... Does that make sense now?

Comment: What is the location of source table? Does it cover Colum A to O?

Comment: the source table is in the TASK - MAP and Validation sheet and is MAV_Table - there is data in A to AN but I only want to copy B to P to MSF_Table A to O

Comment: I have updated the code to answer your question.

Comment: again ... really appreciate you taking the time to help!  I have had another reply from another very helpful member who's approach is to process the records in a loop..so I have 2 solutions to test!

Comment: would it be best to process all the NEW record Types and then Copy the Code and repeat for the UPDATES?  Also is there something in the code that is disabling Automatic calculations as It seems after I run it the cell calculations are not running?

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlManual` disable the auto-calculation.  Microsoft reference document:

> [Application.Calculate method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculate?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461). What are all the NEW record Types?

Comment: sorry getting mixed up with the 2 solutions.... I did write some code that was processing the updates ok it was the adding of the NEW items causing the issue

Comment: I have opted for your solution for the new record add and the other loop solution for for processing update updates - the loop solution with new items was taking forever to complete and the array processing was way above my knowledge... I have added the code to copy the values from B:R but when i execute the paste they go to column c rather than A - been trying to figure out before asking you! also i wanted to reset the table size once updates are made on the source table - again I tried something but not sure I am using right syntax...