# Copy not copying to correct column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I cannot figure out why when I execute the copy it always pastes the results to column 3 and not col 1?

I also tried
VisRange.Copy Destination:=wst.range("a" & MsfT_LastRow)

Thanks in advance

```
 ' Get work sheet
    Set wsf = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
    Set wst = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    
    ' Get table
    Set tblMSFT = wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    Set tblMAV = wsf.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
   
'=====================================================================================
        ' Get the last data row in Map and Validation Table
    
    With tblMSFT.Range
        MsfT_LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    End With
    
'=====================================================================================
     ' Filter table
    tblMAV.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
    
    
    ' Copy filtered table
    Set VisRange = tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, wsf.Columns("B:R"))
    
    If MsfT_LastRow = 2 Then
    VisRange.Copy Destination:=wst.Range("a2")
    Else
    MsfT_LastRow = MsfT_LastRow + 1
    VisRange.Copy Destination:=wst.Cells(MsfT_LastRow, 1)
    End If
```

Comment: Are you trying to add filtered data from `tblMAV` table to the last row of `tblMSFT` table?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: The question is what is the content of VisRange?

Comment: Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, wsf.Columns("B:R"))... I want to copy B:R to a:Q in the destination sheet but it copyies it to C

Comment: the code i wrote works apart from copying the data into the wrong columms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Data From One Table to Another

[image]

- It is assumed that neither table is filtered.

```vb
Sub CopyTableData()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the tables.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects("MAV_Table")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
    
    ' Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    Dim scrg As Range, svrg As Range, srg As Range
    
    With slo
        Set scrg = .DataBodyRange.Resize(, 17).Offset(, 1)
        ' 17 columns in 'B:R'; 1 column to the right (of 'A') is 'B'.
        
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set svrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
    
    If svrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no filtered rows
    
    Set srg = Intersect(svrg, scrg)
    
    ' Reference the first destination cell ('dfcell').
    
    Dim dfcell As Range
    
    With dlo.Range
        If dlo.ListRows.Count = 0 Then ' empty table
            Set dfcell = .Cells(1).Offset(1)
        Else
            Set dfcell = .Cells(1).Offset(.Rows.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    srg.Copy dfcell
    
    MsgBox "Table data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks again.... I used the process you gave me to do the Update piece... this method seemed much quicker when there were 1000's of rows

Comment: If you're saying that this code works but is too slow for you, then use the part starting with `drrg` from my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77225190). The `COLUMNS_COUNT` is obviously 17.

Comment: this worked great but have the same issue whereby it copies to col C and not A in the destination table?

Comment: Maybe the first two columns aren't part of the table. Without at least seeing the screenshot, it's hard to help. Anyway, let me know what the issue was once you figure it out.

Comment: thanks - I will post a screenshot....the Source table range to copy starts in D...

Comment: sorry I though I added a screenshot - just done it

Comment: i recorded macro to replicate what I am trying to do srg.Copy
    Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File").Select
    Range("MSF_Table[Supplier Key]").Select
    MsgBox ("p")
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False.        when I run this when I pause the code at message box the data is selected correctly and column a is selected in the to sheet but still pastes to col c?

Comment: think i sussed it ... it was the values in Visrange...needed to be D:R! thanks for helping me get there!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
'~~> Get work sheet
Set wsf = Sheets("TASK - Map and Validation")
Set wst = Sheets("MASTER - Supplier File")

'~~> Get table
Set tblMSFT = wst.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
Set tblMAV = wsf.ListObjects("MAV_Table")

'~~> Get the last data row in Map and Validation Table
MsfT_LastRow = tblMSFT.Range.Cells(tblMSFT.Range.Cells.Count).Row

'~~> Filter table
tblMAV.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="New"

'~~> Copy filtered table
Set VisRange = tblMAV.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set VisRange = Application.Intersect(VisRange, wsf.Columns("B:R"))

With tblMSFT
    .HeaderRowRange.Offset(Application.Max(1, .ListRows.Count + 1),2).Value = VisRange.Value
End With
```

Comment: the from table has more columns... i posted a screenshot showing the sheets

Comment: I cant see your screenshot. Can you try the above updated code?

Comment: i will do thank you

Comment: sorry took a while - i rested this and it only created 1 record in the destintation file and wrote it starting in col d not col a

Comment: see above comments and I also added screenshoot

Comment: think i sussed it ... it was the values in Visrange...needed to be D:R! thanks for helping me get there!